# How am I select more than 1 item in comobox in VBA? (select 3 itens in the time)

Tags: vba, excel

I am want to select more than 1 item in combobox (in example, I want to be 3 select itens).
**Issue**: The code below works as I expected (the final result=select 3 itens in the combobox - multiple itens selected).However, if possible, I intend to use a code that select the item by the value and not the index. The list index in the combobox changes with some relevant frequency.

Have anyone any solution?

```
Sub Vgbl()

Dim IE As Object
Dim n, Period1, Period2 As Double
Dim MAPFREVI, VIDASEG, CS, Alianca, Brasilv, MapfreSeg, BrasilPrev, SEGUROS, TODAS, BrasilCap As Variant

SEGUROS = "54"
TODAS = "Todas"
Period1 = Sheets("Capa").Cells(4, 3).Value
Period2 = Sheets("Capa").Cells(5, 3).Value

n = Sheets("Ramos").Cells(65, 4).Value

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate "http://www2.susep.gov.br/menuestatistica/SES/principal.aspx"
    IE.Visible = True

While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    'seleciona as operações desejadas
    IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_edSelOp").Value = SEGUROS
    IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnConsultar").Click

    'seleciona o periodo
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    Set ieDoc = IE.document
        ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_edInicioPer").Value = Period1
        ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_edFimPer").Value = Period2

    'seleciona as empresas
    IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_edEmpresas").SelectedIndex = TODAS

    'seleciona os ramos

    Set objListbox = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_edRamos")
    objListbox.Options(n).Selected = True
    n = Sheets("Ramos").Cells(66, 4).Value
    objListbox.Options(n).Selected = True
    n = Sheets("Ramos").Cells(67, 4).Value
    objListbox.Options(n).Selected = True

End sub
```

Comment: A combobox, by design, only ever allows 1 single item to be selected at any given point in time. Also "Issue: This code works!" makes the problem statement rather unclear. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - the HTML select element allows for multiple selections *if* the source allows it by specifying the `multiple` attribute.

Comment: Once you have a reference to the select element, loop over its options and when you find one with the required value, set it as selected.  You should consider coding this function into a separate Sub e.g `Sub SetListByValue(objSelect, theValue)`  Or make it a function so you can return True if the value was found in the list.

Comment: @MAt´s Mug Is it more clear now?